# How to combine different type of items of a questionnaire into a variable

Tags: survey, measurement, cronbachs-alpha

I'm doing a research where I applied a questionnaire with 67 items measuring 5 variables.

The issue is some questions are in Likert scale (0 to 10 and 1 to 5), some Yes, No, some open questions, some ordinal, some nominal. How can I mix those types into a single one in order to have each of those 5 variables?

Also the questionnaire also contains conditional items. E.g., if someone chooses "No" for question 15, he or she will skip question 16 and jump to question 17.

For example:

> 1- Level of education (0-Nothing, 1-Elementary, 2-Secondary school, 3-High school or equivalent 4-University 5-Master, PHD
>
> 12- Type of cell (1-Shared cell, 2-Dormitories)
>
> 15-How many people are imprisoned with you in your cell? (Number... from 0 to 100)
>
> 24-Do you take part of social or recreational programs/activities? (1-Yes, 2-No)
>
> 35-From 0 to 10, what your level of stress (Likert with 11 elements from 0 to >10)
>
> 46-Do you think rules are fair for you and fellow inmates (Likert with 5 elements, from strongly agree to strongly disagree)
>
> 57-Do you get psychologic exams? 1-Yes, 2-No
>   If not, skip question 58, go to 59...
>
> 66-In your opinion, what's the main reason behind inmate misbehavior?
>   ___ open answer

This is a small summary, i have 67 questions of those types...

Because now I think I cant do the Cronbach alpha. Most of the examples i've seen contain like 4 Likert questions, 40 subjects, in my case my questions are different, not in this same scale.

I'm using Stata.

Comment: I suppose the questionnaire has scoring rules, that tells you what to count and how to obtain  the 5 scales you are measuring

Comment: yes, but each variable has different types of items. That's my concern. For example, for variable Communication, there are some Likert, some yes/no, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Stata, my view is that you can use alpha q1 q2 q3 q4, std

That std will help you no matter the type of item.